# Setting UILabel to Same value as NSString

Tags: xcode, string, label, nslog

I have searched for hours on this one subject and still have not been able to solve my problem. I have a string value that I need converted into a label. In my code I save the NSString and then make sure I am getting a value with the NSLog (which I DO). Then is where I am having problems. I try to set the label value equal to the nesting but when I run its NSLog I get (null). So my question is how may I make my label equal the value of my string? Thank you so much!

```
NSString *linkString = self.product[@"link"];

NSLog(@"%@", linkString);

linkLabel.text = linkString;

NSLog(@"%@", linkLabel);
```

Comment: Where are you initializing your label?

Comment: I am doing so in my .h file.  {
    IBOutlet UILabel *linkLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *linkLabel;

Answer (score 2):

Your NSString will never be equal to your UILabel.

on the other hand, your UILabel's text property which is an NSString will be

try to change the code to this

```
NSString *linkString = self.product[@"link"];

NSLog(@"%@", linkString);

linkLabel.text = linkString;

NSLog(@"%@", linkLabel.text);
```

All I changed was linkLabel in your NSLog to linkLabel.text

Assuming like you said that linkString has a value, the second log should output the same as the first log.

EDIT: I saw your comment above, there is no need for a duplicate definition of the label as an @property and above that in the h file.

Comment: Okay so I tried that and Still my log is outputting my value for the linkString, and then the label linkLabel is still outputting as (null). I have also attempted to prove this and found out that Yes the linkLabel still has no value! haha I have no idea what is wrong! Thank you so much though!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

```
NSString *linkString = self.product[@"link"];
```

works? Try this:

```
NSString *linkString = @"Test";
```

and use this for logging:

```
NSLog(@"%@", linkLabel.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to hook up the linkLabel in your XIB? Is the value of linkLabel not nil?
What does `NSLog(@"%@", linkLabel);` print out?